# Modular arithmetic: Reaching an interval

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Given $n=2^w$, where $w$ is the word length.

Consider an interval $[c_1,c_2]$, where $0\leq c_1,c_2\leq 2^w-1$, and let the interval length be $d$. Also, consider an operation $+\delta$, where $0\leq \delta < n$ and is coprime with $n$. This forms finite cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/n$, and $\delta$ is generator of this group

Now, given $x$, the problem is to obtain minimal $k$ such that $(x+k\delta)$ mod $n \in [c_1,c_2]$, when $\delta > d$

Is there a compact way to represent this in terms of $x$, $\delta$, and $d$?

Answer (score 2):

This is the best that I can come up with.

Since $\delta$ is co-prime to $n$, it has an inverse in $Z_n$. Let $\gamma$ be the integer in $\{ 0, 1, \dots, n - 1 \}$ that equals this inverse modulo $n$. Then, $k = \min\{ \gamma m \pmod n : c_1 - x \leq m \leq c_2 - x \}$.